# Why can you express Content as a string in XAML?

Tags: windows, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

I was looking through the [Windows universal samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/XamlNavigation/cs/Styles/Styles.xaml#L19) and I noticed a strange style for a `ToggleButton` that expressed its `Content` as a string:

```
<Setter Property="Content" Value="&#xE700;"/>
```

When I removed the line, the hamburger button disappeared from the designer in `AppShell.xaml`. When I uncommented it out, the button magically reappeared. I wasn't able to reproduce this in my project.

The app had no asset that was a hamburger button.

Can somebody explain how this works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&#xE700;` is the Hamburger symbol in the `Segoe MDL2 Assets` font, used for common symbols.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<Setter Property="Content" Value="&#xE700;"/>
```

with this statement you are setting up the content or soemthing and whose value is `&#xE700;` so where you will set this style to content of control it will show thisHamburger button.